# Gauss-Jordan elimination in the form of (A|I)

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, gaussian-elimination

So Gauss-Jordan elimination can be performed through the form of $(A|I)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. We carry out row elementary operations as usual until the matrix becomes the form $(I|B)$, then the matrix $B$ is the inverse of $A$.

My question is, if I apply Gauss-Jordan elimination without taking into account
the structure of the identity matrix in the initial form $(A|I)$ of the augmented matrix,
then the computation of A$^{-1}$ requires $3n^3 − 2n^2$ arithmetic operations. I do not understand how this numbers come into meaning. The book says that it is an easy derivation from the operation count $n^3+n^2-n$ of Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Thanks for any input

Comment: I believe the qualification "without taking into account the structure of the identity amounts to asking for reduced row echelon form of a $n\times 2n$ matrix.  You should try repeating the operation count for GJ-elimination "as if" there were $n$ right-hand sides to revise, rather than a single one.

Comment: @hardmath: I tried changing the number of columns from n+1 to 2n+2 and played around with it but still couldn't get that exact number.

Comment: Okay, it would actually be changing from $n+1$ to $2n$ columns.